# How does `make_heap` compare to `heap`

Tags: c++

So I recently learned of the `make_heap` function. Thinking. Oh, that is a nice way of creating multiple heaps which can be used as a memory resource for `new`.

But after reading more about `make_heap` it is something completly different from the normal heap.

What is the reasoning behind these naming conventions? Because AFAIK they are something completly different.

Comment: Because the C++ standard never refers to a heap in the first place the way you describe it. It refers to the free-store, that's it. The compiler implementation can decide how to implement this free store. It usually uses a heap but this is not required by the standard at all. `std::make_heap` does just that, it creates an actual heap structure.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947394/what-is-the-point-of-make-heap

Comment: @SombreroChicken: *"It usually uses a heap"* -- You mean, as in the 
 heap data structure? This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure) ? -- I can't imagine why it would. But I'm not an expert in memory allocation algorithms. As far as I understood, this was always just a case of two unrelated things being given the same name.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The older languages did, major compilers these days, not so much, you're right. Pool would be a better name nowadays.

Comment: Thanks guys. I searched and searched but didn't find the answers you guys linked. Once more, thanks :-) Sorry for the duplicate question.